# Create a vertical video scroll based on an image using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am creating a video scroll vertical image with ffmpeg.

My code

```
ffmpeg -loop 1  -t 61 -i 0.jpg  -filter_complex "color=white:s=1280x720[bg];[bg][0]overlay=y=-'t*120':shortest=1[video]"  -r 200/1 -preset ultrafast -map [video] "D:\FFMPEG\output.mp4"
```

But the video is very bad. Although I set the frame rate at 200, it is jerky.

My source image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBQXU.jpg)

And result [result video](https://youtu.be/8sKMOkxG8oE)

Comment: try matching the framerate to expected usage (making it 'faster' won't make it smoother as youTube etc will transcode it to match a supported profile - https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en - also, pick a preset from the slower end of the range to improve the encoding (it'll take longer, but the result will probably look better)

Comment: The video what in local and set frame rate at 60 is jerky too. I think problem in code overlay=y=-'t*120'

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I posted inputs , you can test.Thank!

Comment: try making t equal to frames/sec * time of the clip ... that way the steps match. I get a different result to your example clip (white background overlays) but it looks smoother when the values match

Comment: t = time of the clip. I thought due to the sampling time of overlay in filter_complex. But I don't know to change sampling time.@Offbeatmammal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -t 61 -i 0.jpg -filter_complex "color=white:s=1280x720, fps=fps=60[bg];[bg][0]overlay=y=-'t*120':shortest=1[video]" -preset ultrafast -map [video] output.mp4
```

You need to [set the frame rate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate) `fps=fps=60` ([default is 25](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps)). `-r 1` is for faster processing.

[Result video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXX79hBBXsk).

Comment: Thanks, Its awesome.
I used it but I need 2 more options:
1. Wait X seconds before start scrolling
2. Wait X seconds after scrolling ends before ends the video

Comment: My video produced by this command scrolls not to the end of the image but interrupts somewhere in the middle :-(

Comment: @porton I realise this may be too late, but the problem is the `-t 61` part of the above command. That limits the video to 61 seconds. Remove it and it shouldn't get cut any more!